# bitcoin historical data (both daily and intraday)

Tags: historical-trade-data

I am looking for historical daily time series of bitcoin/eur (or bitcoin against USD) and, if they exist, of other major criptocurrencies possibly since inception.

I am looking for intraday historical data for bitcoin as well. The level of granularity I am looking for is not necessarily tick by tick, price quotes every 5-10 mins would be enough.

Are these two types of historical data available for cryptocurrencies? As I can understand, there should be something in quandl but only at daily level.